# how do i check if session ID exist from one table exist in another table and echo out error or success code

Tags: php, mysql

how do i check if session ID exist from one table column exist in another table column and echo out error or success code.

i have tried the following but its not echoing anything out

```
<?php
$result = $DBcon->query("SELECT username, email, Phone_number, subcription  FROM tbl_users join mergeing on tbl_users.user_id = mergeing.donator_1 where mergeing.donor  = {$_SESSION['userSession']}");
if(!$result){
    echo "user does not exist in Db";
}
else{
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ Please don't inline variables in query strings, you're just asking for trouble!  Use prepared statements instead.   Also, what debugging have you done?  Have you configured error_reporting and display and/or log errors?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using this

```
$result = $DBcon->query("SELECT username, email, Phone_number, subcription FROM tbl_users join mergeing on tbl_users.user_id = mergeing.donator_1 where mergeing.donor  = {$_SESSION['userSession']}");
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "YOU HAVE NOT YET BEEN CONFIRMED";
}else{
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
echo $row['username']; 
}
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ Please don't inline variables in query strings, you're just asking for trouble! Use prepared statements instead